# MySQL to return NULL if there is no result

Tags: mysql

I have this type of query

```
SELECT one, two, three FROM (
  ( SELECT data AS one FROM thetable WHERE `id` = '$id' AND name = 'one') t1,
  ( SELECT data AS two FROM thetable WHERE `id` = '$id' AND name = 'two') t2,  
  ( SELECT data AS three FROM thetable WHERE `id` = '$id' AND name = 'three') t3
)
```

and when one of the row is missing for a certain `id`, it just skips all of the selects related to the `id`.

I'm hoping to get something like this:

```
id:24     one:somedata      two:somedata      three:somedata
id:25     one:somedata      two:EMPTY         three:somedata
id:26     one:somedata      two:somedata      three:somedata
id:27     one:EMPTY         two:somedata      three:somedata
```

but I'm getting:

```
id:24     one:somedata      two:somedata      three:somedata
id:25     one:EMPTY         two:EMPTY         three:EMPTY
id:26     one:somedata      two:somedata      three:somedata
id:27     one:EMPTY         two:EMPTY         three:EMPTY
```

Why?

Comment: Please use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years!!!

Comment: @Eric can you elaborate, please? What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below way -

```
select id,
max(case when  name = 'one' then data end) as one,
max(case when  name = 'two' then data end) as two,
max(case when  name = 'three' then data end) as three
from thetable where `id` = '$id'
group by id
```

Comment: You probably want to move the condition `id = '$id'` to the `WHERE`-clause so the query can use an index on `id`.

Comment: @slaakso, yes you are right, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Wow, thank you! It works, and it works 10 times faster! Why is that? It takes 3 seconds to finish the query, whereas my query was taking 30 seconds to complete.